# How to show that a differential equation has an integrating factor of a specific form

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, integrating-factor

I am given the differential equation

$$4x^2y + 3xy^2 + 2y^3 + (2x^3 + 3x^2y + 4xy^2)\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$$

and I am asked to show that this equation has an integrating factor $\mu \equiv \mu(xy)$. Setting $M(x,y) = 4x^2y + 3xy^2 + 2y^3$ and $N(x,y) = 2x^3 + 3x^2y + 4xy^2$ I know that I want to show that, for some $\mu$ that is a function of $xy$, I have that

$$\mu(xy) M(x,y) + \mu(xy) N(x,y)\frac{dy}{dx} = 0$$ is an exact equation, i.e.

$$\frac{\partial (\mu M)}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial (\mu N)}{\partial x}$$

setting $v = xy$ and taking the derivatives, knowing that

$$\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial x} = y\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial v}, \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial y} = x\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial v}$$

I will eventually get to

$$\frac{\mu '}{\mu} = \frac1{xy}$$

where I wrote $\mu '$ instead of $\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial v}$.

My question is, is that enough to show that the equation indeed has an integrating factor $\mu(xy)$? Or do I need to explicitly solve for $\mu$ and show that it depends only on $(xy)$?

Comment: Just explicitly solve for it, it's about 2 more steps than what you've already done.

Comment: @Mattos I know I am almost there, but if I can justify it already at this step, I'd rather save time for other problems. Plus, I am more interested in the theoretical explanation of why I can (or can't) stop here than seeing the actual solution.

Comment: Then per your question, you need to demonstrate that $\mu = \mu(xy)$. What you have shown is that $\mu' / \mu = 1/v$. This is not the same (yet). So no, you haven't shown what was asked.

Comment: @Mattos but then again, why isn't it that what I have isn't enough to show what I want.

Comment: I got the answer by putting $u=\dfrac {y}{x}$, but it's messy.